# How to achieve triggered redirect after log in so that administration interface will be available on the redirected url? Drupal 7

Tags: authentication, triggers, drupal-7, base-url

I would like to ask for an advice. Recently, I was developing a conference site with Drupal 7. The site is hosted at domain1.com. However, the conference is covered by another organization and they require that conference page will be accessible from their own domain something like.: organization.com/conference2014 Fortunately, Drupal has base_url parameter and the site is accessible from organization.com/conference2014 domain. BUt, my problem is when I want to access administration interface of Drupal through organization.com/conference2014?q=user/login I get redirected to organization.com site which is administrated by the organization admin. Moreover, when I access again organization.com/conference2014 - it still asks me for the password.

I got adviced to introduce trigger after the user successfully logs in to the site organization.com/conference2014. It does redirect me but the administration interface/overlays is not there. Any ideas how to tackle this problem?

Martin

Answer (score 1):

Your session cookie is associated with the domain you logged in at, so if you login at domain1.com you will not be logged in at organization.com. I'm assuming organization.com has a RewriteRule configured for conference2014 which points to your domain? If so, they can configure the redirect to pass the query string with the redirect, like this:

```
RewriteRule ^conference2014/?(.*) http://domain1.com/$1 [L,NE,QSA]
```

(QSA is the piece which we're interested in, it is "Query String Append")

This will allow you to access http://organization.com/conference2014?q=user etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that is not my problem. I am able to access  http://organization.com/conference2014?q=user/login page - however, my problem is that after I enter my credentials I am redirected to the page organization.com?user/login - my login procedure failed. The original question was a kind of workaround but  i did not manage to make it work. Anyway, thanks for the help.